# Problema ao criar projeto Android Studio no Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

Instalei o Android Studio, mas quando vou criar um projeto ou abrir um já existente aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Error:Could not determine Java version using executable
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/bin/java.

Comment: Tente isto: http://askubuntu.com/questions/467870/how-to-set-the-jdk-for-android-studio

Comment: abra o terminal e digite `java -version`, e infome a versão que foi exibida

Answer (score 1):

Siga os seguintes passos :

- terminal aberto no Ubuntu : `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`
- abrir android estúdio : `FILE> Outras Configurações> Estrutura do Projeto Padrão`. Na seção `JDK Localização` colocar a url da instalação do Oracle Java7 , geralmente é `usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/`

Para desenvolver aplicativos para Android para Android 5.0 e acima você precisa JAVA SDK7 como eu disse a você para instalar aqui. JAVA 8 é recomendado , mas eu só posso dizer que me leva Java7 1,5 GB de RAM, e JAVA8 leva 2GB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow in Portuguese. In case you haven't noticed, this is the SO Portuguese community, You should translante your answer